# Supremum Infimum argument: what did I do wrong?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

> Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon_0$ for all $x,y\in[a,b]$. Then $M-m\le\epsilon_0$, where $M=\sup\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$ and $m=\inf\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}$.

I went this way: suppose $M-m>\epsilon_0$, hence $M>\epsilon_0+m$, hence there is an $x\in[a,b]$ such that$$M>f(x)>\epsilon_0+m,\tag1$$and similarly $M-\epsilon_0>m$ implies$$M-\epsilon_0>f(y)>m.\tag2$$Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$ says $-\epsilon_0>f(y)-f(x)>-\epsilon_0$, which is absurd.

But on a second thought, I realized that my argument says that $M-m>\varepsilon$ is false for any $\varepsilon>0$, not just for $\epsilon_0$, implying $M-m=0$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I hope that you don't mind about the way I've edited your question.

Comment: Also, you only use the fact that $M$ is an upper-bound, not a supremum. Same remark for $m$. To solve you exercise, remark that for all $x,y\in [a,b]$ $f(y)-\varepsilon_0 <f(x)<f(y)+\varepsilon _0$. The conclusion is straightforward.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, no, in fact, this seems awesome. Thank you

Comment: An additional minor error in your proof (unrelated to the problem you noticed): You are guaranteed an $x$ such that $M \ge f(x) > \epsilon_0 + m$, but you are not guaranteed that $M > f(x)$. It could be that $f(x_0) = M$ and for every other $x \ne x_0, f(x) < m + \epsilon_0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mistake is thinking you can just subtract inequalities. You can't do that. For example,

$$1>0$$

is true, and $$2>0$$ is also true, but subtracting these two inequalities, I get $$-1>0$$ which is not true.

---

The problem with subtracting inequalities is that when you subtract equations, you actually multiply one of them by $(-1)$ and then add them. With inequalities, you cannot do that because multiplication by a negative number reverses the inequality.

---

For an actual proof, a sketch of it would be this:

- Find some $x$ for which $f(x)$ is "near" $M$
- Find some $y$ for which $f(y)$ is "near" $m$
- Use the fact that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon_0$ and the fact that $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-M+M-f(y)+m-m|\leq |f(x)-M| + |f(y)-m| + |M-m|$$ to reach a conclusion.

Naturally, the "near" in this sketch must, in the final proof, be a more rigorous statement. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Last step is wrong. $a\leq b\leq c$ and $a'\leq b'\leq c'$ do not imply $a-a'\leq b-b'\leq c-c'$.

Answer (score 1):

You may also proceed as follows:

- Note that $|x|$ is continuous.
- Choose sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = M$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = m$.

It follows:
$$|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} M-m$$
Now, as $|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| < \epsilon_0 \Rightarrow M-m \leq \epsilon_0$.